# How to map generate_series with Slick?

Tags: postgresql, scala, slick

I am willing to use the `generate_series` function from Postgres, but I don't know how to write the mapper in Slick to call it.

Description of `generate_series` can be found here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html

Has anyone any clue ?

Thank you.

Comment: http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/userdefined.html

Comment: I know that page, but that is more for defining function that will be used like `SELECT fun(x) FROM ...` and here, it's more like `SELECT * FROM generate_series(...)`

Answer (score 0):

I believe for functions that return complete tables the only way in Slick is to use PLain SQL Queries.
In the [link](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/userdefined.html) it specifically reads out "For database functions that return complete tables or stored procedures please use Plain SQL Queries. "

So i guess you would want to use plain Sql queries via Slick [here](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/sql.html).